How to fix SIGSEGV SoundPool error on android 14
On android 14 in Play Console began to appear error SoundPool SIGSEGV. There was no such error on other android versions. The app plays different sounds for pranks when you press a button. Can you tell me what is the cause of this error and how to fix it?
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000008ebd0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__strlen_aarch64+16)
  #01  pc 0x00000000000c1468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__strlen_chk+20)
  #02  pc 0x00000000000d9d10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__vfprintf+8076)
  #03  pc 0x00000000000f759c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (vsnprintf+196)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000006d5c  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_print+188)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000019b20  /system_ext/lib64/libaudioclientimpl.so (android::AudioRepeatStartStopCheck::isRepeatStartStopOnetrackCheck(int, int, int, int, int)+572)
  #06  pc 0x000000000001967c  /system_ext/lib64/libaudioclientimpl.so (android::AudioRepeatStartStopCheck::isManytimesStartInBackstage(int*, int*, int, int, int, char const*)+740)
  #07  pc 0x00000000000162f8  /system_ext/lib64/libaudioclientimpl.so (android::audiotrackstub::AudioTrackImpl::audioRepeatStartStopCheck(char const*, android::AudioTrack const*)+320)
  #08  pc 0x00000000000b633c  /system/lib64/libaudioclient.so (android::AudioTrack::start()+412)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000012d78  /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so (android::soundpool::Stream::play_l(std::__1::shared_ptr<android::soundpool::Sound> const&, int, float, float, int, int, float, std::__1::vector<std::__1::any, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::any> >&, int)+1424)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000012754  /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so (android::soundpool::Stream::playPairStream(std::__1::vector<std::__1::any, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::any> >&, int)+432)
  #11  pc 0x0000000000014718  /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so (android::soundpool::StreamManager::queueForPlay(std::__1::shared_ptr<android::soundpool::Sound> const&, int, float, float, int, int, float, int)+940)
  #12  pc 0x0000000000011334  /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so (android::SoundPool::play(int, float, float, int, int, float, int)+420)
  #13  pc 0x000000000000b6c0  /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so (android_media_SoundPool_play(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, float, float, int, int, float, int)+200)
  #14  pc 0x000000000032d4d4  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+116)
  #15  pc 0x000000000031f17c  /data/app/~~5_vGF6RC1JJSWL1jjAXh3A==/st.soundboard.sirenpranksound-SGExlnqinadXQ4YNlCvCBQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (st.soundboard.sirenpranksound.MainActivity$Companion.runnablePlay+764)
  #16  pc 0x00000000005b9610  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+5648)
  #17  pc 0x00000000002058c6  /data/app/~~5_vGF6RC1JJSWL1jjAXh3A==/st.soundboard.sirenpranksound-SGExlnqinadXQ4YNlCvCBQ==/base.apk (st.soundboard.sirenpranksound.runnable.RunnableGun$stun2$1.run+42)
  #18  pc 0x0000000000998b94  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+68)
  #19  pc 0x000000000099c714  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+1044)
  #20  pc 0x000000000099c264  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+916)
  #21  pc 0x00000000007322dc  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+1372)
  #22  pc 0x000000000033aa80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+640)
  #23  pc 0x000000000037bf18  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1556)
  #24  pc 0x000000000037b8f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277)+32)
  #25  pc 0x0000000000332f88  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+120)
  #26  pc 0x0000000000cc2954  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+116)
  #27  pc 0x0000000000ccda88  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3448)
  #28  pc 0x000000000033aa80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+640)
  #29  pc 0x00000000004e1f4c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+728)
  #30  pc 0x000000000057a164  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+156)
  #31  pc 0x00000000000e6be8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+108)
  #32  pc 0x00000000000f3e6c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+924)
  #33  pc 0x00000000000027a4  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1868)
  #34  pc 0x000000000008d99c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108)

This is how I initialize SoundPool
val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()

        soundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
            .setMaxStreams(50)
            .build()

I don't know how to fix this error
